# Content of bootstrap popover doesn't fit its shape (Android)

Tags: android, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover, angular-ui-bootstrap

In my web application I use popovers (from ui-bootstrap). Everything works correctly, but I noticed some problems on Android. The problem is that text (content) of popover doesn't fit its shape. Text is inside and outside. It happens only near edge of the screen - shape of popover is adjusted to the page (it doesn't stick out beyond window), but text is not adjusted.

I prepared short example. You should display it on Android:
http://plnkr.co/edit/IJyN0yUBud7hUrNJmqs3?p=preview

Does anyone knows how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Going to have to specify what browser this is in. This is fine in Android with Chrome. But Popovers are not responsive, so when a popopver is on the extreme left or right, use the left or right direction. See the older docs. Though if it's the stock android browser, Bootstrap doesn't officially support it.